# How many ways can 21 consonants can combine with 5 vowels in the form VC and CV

Tags: combinatorics

Hello everyone I am very new to combinatorics. I am applying some combinatorial questions to linguistics at the moment.

I wish to calculate the combinations of 21 consonants and 5 vowels in the following format: VC and CV (Vowels and consonants and consonants and vowels), just forming a string of 2 characters for the sake of simplicity.

So I begin as followed:

**Vowels:** $A, I, E, O, U$ (5 vowels)

**Consonants:** $B, C, D, F, G, J, K, L, M, N, P, Q, S, T, V, X, Z, H, R, W, Y$ (21 consonants)

I reason that:

For each vowel, there are 26 ways to combine with 26 consonants.
5 vowels combining with 21 consonants would be: $5\cdot 21 = 105$

For each consonant, there are 5 ways to combine with 5 vowels:
26 consonants combining with 5 vowels would be: $21\cdot 5 = 105$

Is this correct? I have a strong feeling that it is wrong. I am not sure if it is $5^{21}$ or $5\cdot 21$. Both ways could be wrong as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that for every $VC$ string, its reverse string is $CV$ string. There should an equal number of both.

To convince yourself that is indeed $5\times 21$, there are $21$ strings starting with A, $21$ with E, $21$ with I, $21$ with O and $21$ with U, giving $5\times 21.$

Comment: Thank you! Mathematically, perhaps the difference between $VC$ and $CV$ is not important, but from a linguistic standpoint, they do differ. For $BA$ is not $AB$.

Comment: @JamesWarthington  Since order is important, the answer should be $2 \cdot 5 \cdot 21 = 210$.

Answer (score 2):

Each vowel can combine with each consonant in $^5C_1\times^{21}C_1 = 105$ ways

But order also matters, because you are treating VC and CV as different, so we need to multiply by $2$

Thus there can be $210$ different arrangements of a vowel and a consonant

Comment: Thank you. I do see those formulae for permutation and combination, but as an absolute beginner, I would like to do a bit of "plumbing" to get a feeling for it. Obviously now if the format is CVV and VVC, for example, the task of calculating would be quite daunting and one needs to recourse to formulae.