# How many ways can 21 consonants can combine with 5 vowels in the form CVV

Tags: combinatorics

There are:

**Vowels:** $A, I, E, O, U$ (5 vowels)

**Consonants:** $B, C, D, F, G, J, K, L, M, N, P, Q, S, T, V, X, Z, H, R, W, Y$ (21 consonants)

I am trying to calculate the number of combinations of these alphabets following the rule CVV (Consonant+Vowel+Vowel). I just follow blindly the calculation.

How many ways are there to choose 1 out of 21 consonants? There are $^{21}C_1 = 21$ ways

How many ways are there to choose 2 out of 10 vowels? There are $^{10}C_2 = 45$ ways

The total number of combinations of 21 vowels and 10 consonants is $^{21}C_1 \cdot ^{10}C_2 = 45\cdot21= 945$

Is this the correct answer?

If this is correct, I still don't understand this problem at more intuitive level as in  [this previous topic](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4632111/how-many-ways-can-21-consonants-can-combine-with-5-vowels-in-the-form-vc-and-cv/4632117#4632117)

Comment: There are not 10 vowels. There are 5 choices for the first vowel, and again 5 choices for the second vowel (presuming that they do not need to be distinct).

Comment: See [rule of product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_product)

Comment: @DanielMathias: So there are $5\cdot 5$ ways of combining 10 vowels among themselves, provided that they are not distinct?

Comment: Sorry $5^5$, my mistake

Comment: **There are not 10 vowels.** Saying that there are implies a gross misunderstanding. There are 5 vowels, providing 5 *options* for each position in which a vowel is required. With 21 options for the consonant, the number of strings of the form CVV is $21\times 5\times 5$ by the rule of product. Multiplication, not exponentiation.

Comment: It is indeed a gross misunderstanding on my part.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How many ways are there to choose 1 out of 21 consonants for the first letter?

- There are $^{21}C_1 = 21$ ways.

How many ways are there to choose 1 out of 5 vowels for the second letter?

- There are $^{5}C_1 = 5$ ways.

How many ways are there to choose 1 out of 5 vowels for the third letter?

- There are $^{5}C_1 = 5$ ways.

The total number of strings of the form CVV is $21\times 5\times 5=525$ by rule of product.